# How to use Single Sign On Credentials for QTest Rest APIs Access

Tags: single-sign-on, qtestlib, qtest

I'm Using the QTest APIs for the Automation. I authenticate using a Login API With username/password, get a bearer token, and use the token for the next API calls.

[image]

But if I use SSO Credentials (Username/Password) in the same API It gives an error

[image]

**I want to use SSO Credentials OR SAML response programmatically to authenticate and get an Access Token. Is there any way to use SSO Credentials OR SAML Response to get the bearer Token using Postman?**

**Is there any technical documentation that will help me?**

**Does Qtest provide any mechanism to get a bearer token programmatically using SSO credentials?**

Answer (score -1):

Integrating Single Sign-On (SSO) with QTest Rest APIs involves a few steps to ensure secure and authenticated access. SSO systems can vary, so the specific steps may differ depending on the SSO provider and QTest configuration. However, here's a general outline of how you can achieve SSO authentication for QTest Rest APIs:

1.Understand Your SSO Provider: First, you need to understand the SSO provider you are using (e.g., Okta, Azure AD, Auth0, or a custom SSO solution). You will need to configure your QTest application to work with your specific SSO provider.

2.Configure QTest Application:

Access the administration settings in your QTest application.
Configure the SSO settings to integrate with your SSO provider. This usually involves specifying the SSO provider's metadata URL, client ID, and other necessary information.
Follow the instructions provided by QTest or your SSO provider to set up SAML (Security Assertion Markup Language) or OpenID Connect (OIDC) for SSO.

3.API Access Configuration:

Once SSO is set up for your QTest application, you can configure access to the QTest Rest APIs.
You may need to generate an API token or access key within the QTest application's settings. This token will be used to authenticate API requests.
Depending on your QTest API usage, you may need to configure specific API permissions or scopes for your SSO-authenticated users.

4.Implement SSO in Your Client Application:

In your client application (the one that will make API requests), you need to implement the SSO flow. This typically involves redirecting users to the SSO provider's login page.
When a user logs in through SSO, they receive an authentication token.
Your client application should then use this authentication token when making API requests to QTest.

5.Make Authenticated API Requests:

In your client application, include the SSO authentication token in the HTTP headers when making API requests to QTest.
The specific way to do this can depend on the programming language and HTTP library you are using.

6.Handle Token Renewal and Expiry:

SSO tokens usually have a limited lifetime, so you may need to handle token renewal or refreshing when the token expires.
Many SSO providers offer token refresh mechanisms, and you'll need to implement this logic in your client application.
Testing and Debugging: Test your SSO integration thoroughly. Make sure that API requests are correctly authenticated and that user access is properly controlled.

7.Monitor and Maintain: Continuously monitor your SSO and API integration for any issues or changes. Keep your client application and SSO configurations up to date.

Remember that the specifics of SSO integration can vary widely based on your SSO provider and the QTest configuration. It's essential to refer to the documentation provided by QTest and your SSO provider for detailed setup instructions and best practices.